# Selenium - Unable to find the count of element

Tags: java, selenium

**Actual**:- I am looking for an element on the page. If the condition evaluates to true then the code works but if the element is not found then the code fails.

**Expected**:- Evaluate the IF part is the element is found or move to the else part
Why is it so because the similar thing used to work earlier

```
if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("MyLocator")).size()!=0)
                {
                    continue;
                }
else {
execute the else part
}
```

Comment: Do you have this in a loop ?

Comment: Yes it is inside a loop

Comment: How is question heading _count of element_ and description _looking for an element on the page_ related? Sounds to be two different usecases.

Comment: if the count of the element is greater than 0 then the element is displayed on the page

Comment: Please share the exact code, not in pieces for further analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add explicit waits before this IF statement for locator, `By.xpath("MyLocator")`?